# Add waypoints to ArcMap using GPSBabel

Tags: arcmap, gps, mac, file-formats, gpsbabel

I've been trying to add waypoints to Arcmap for some while now. I have a Mac OS X 10.6.8 and have finally found GPSBabel that is compatible with mac. My current problem is to convert the waypoints from the gps to a format which allows me to add the waypoints to Arcmap ( I don't know which output format to choose and convert it to a shapefile or x;y data to add to Arcmap)

Note: DNRgps is NOT compatible with Mac

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user of this site I hope you don't mind me pointing out that I have removed your "signature" from your question.  From the help: 

**Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.**

Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. If you use an additional signature or tagline, it will be removed to reduce noise in the questions and answers. 

Your user page belongs to you — fill it with information about your interests, links to stuff you’ve worked on, or whatever else you like!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used GPSBabel. Based on the [list of supported formats](http://www.gpsbabel.org/capabilities.html), I would try to use csv (csv) or universal csv (unicsv) or kml. If the file format supports different formats for the latitude/longitude values, try to use a signed decimal degree format, +/-DDD.ddddd.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is probably by converting directly to the "unicsv" format, which gives a header row.

To download (`-w` waypoints only) direct from the gps:

```
gpsbabel -w -i garmin -f usb: -o unicsv -F GPSwaypoints.csv
```

If you've already downloaded to, say, GPX:

```
gpsbabel -w -i gpx -f GPSwaypoints.gpx -o unicsv -F GPSwaypoints.csv
```

Then you can 'add XY coordinates' in ArcMap.